# ThreadSafeObservableCollection of (T)

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

The idea here is to implement a simple, threadsafe, observable collection that clients can bind to, whilst background threads can update. Changes in the contained items raise the `CollectionChanged` event.

Feedback appreciated:

```
public class ThreadSafeObservableCollection<T> : INotifyCollectionChanged
    where T: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly Object _lock = new Object();
    private readonly Collection<T> _items = new Collection<T>();
    private ReadOnlyCollection<T> _readonlyItems;

    public ThreadSafeObservableCollection()
    {

    }

    public ThreadSafeObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        _items = new ObservableCollection<T>(items);
        foreach (T item in _items)
        {
            ((INotifyPropertyChanged) item).PropertyChanged += ItemPropertyChangedHandler;
        }  
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<T> Items
    {
        get { return _readonlyItems ?? (_readonlyItems = new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(_items)); }
    }

    public virtual void Add(T obj)
    {
        lock(_lock)
        {
            ((INotifyPropertyChanged) obj).PropertyChanged += ItemPropertyChangedHandler;
            _items.Add(obj);
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, obj));
        }
    }

    public virtual void Remove(T obj)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            ((INotifyPropertyChanged) obj).PropertyChanged -= ItemPropertyChangedHandler;
            _items.Remove(obj);
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, obj));
        }
    }


    #region INotify Members

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var copy = CollectionChanged;
        if(copy != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, args);
        }
    }

    private void ItemPropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        OnCollectionChanged(args);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Update**

In response to the comments about the ReadOnlyCollection, I have switch its implementation for a yield block that is locked (Using a ReaderWriterLock) for the length of the enumeration, like so:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> Items
    {
        get
        {
            _lock.AcquireReaderLock(_lockTimeout);
            try
            {
                foreach (T item in _items)
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _lock.ReleaseReaderLock();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: why item's `propertyChanged` raises `Reset` on the entire collection?

Answer (score 6):

Your `Items` initialization I believe isn't threadsafe. Use [`Lazy<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) for thread safe lazy initialization instead.

The [`ReadOnlyCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) isn't thread safe.

> A ReadOnlyCollection can support
> multiple readers concurrently, as long
> as the collection is not modified.
> Even so, enumerating through a
> collection is intrinsically not a
> thread-safe procedure. To guarantee
> thread safety during enumeration, you
> can lock the collection during the
> entire enumeration. To allow the
> collection to be accessed by multiple
> threads for reading and writing, you
> must implement your own
> synchronization.

Consider using a [`ReaderWriterLock`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlock?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) to support a single writer, but multiple readers.

---

Furthermore, consider reading [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528999/why-arent-classes-like-bindinglist-or-observablecollection-thread-safe/529028#529028), and the blog post mentioned there, which discusses [why thread safe collections are so hard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaredpar/why-are-thread-safe-collections-so-hard), and not necessarily useful.

Answer (score 2):

The Remove function, removes the object without checking if the object is in the collection.
This will probably work fine for most cases, but it would be better to make sure the object can be removed before actually modifying the object itself and the collection.

What if the object in question belonged to another collection?
This code

```
((INotifyPropertyChanged) obj).PropertyChanged -= ItemPropertyChangedHandler;
```

would actually remove the change handler from the object but would not remove the object from the correct list.

Another thing I noticed was

```
var copy = CollectionChanged;
if(copy != null)
```

At first I though you made a copy of the event handler to make sure another thread is not changing it in between testing for null and calling it, but then you call the handler directly, so why make the copy at all? (maybe there's a good reason, I just don't know it myself)

Sometimes I find it handy to declare the event with an empty delegate, this way I never have to test for null before calling it:

```
public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged = delegate {};
```

I'm not sure if this makes the code slower as this empty method will be called every time the event is raised, but even if it is, in some cases it might be worth the trade off.

Comment: **(1)** The Remove() also throws an exception when calling it incorrectly on an ordinary collection, so I would preserve that analogy. **(2)** Removing the event handler won't do anything wrong, it refers to the event handler of this class, which was never added. **(3)** Relating to the copy made of the event handler, read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/786383/590790).

Comment: I did mean to raise the copy, rather than the original. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a warning, the main problem with the implementation of Items is that it lets a caller totally block write access by not finishing the iteration (i.e. blocking). You really leave yourself exposed. Which might be totally fine, but you should be aware of the issues opened up by your design.

From Jon Skeets [C# in depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx):

> It's worth remembering that most finally blocks in code aren't written explicitly in C# - they're generated by the compiler as part of lock and using statements. lock is particularly dangerous in iterator blocks - any time you've got a yield return statement inside a lock block, you've got a threading issue waiting to happen. Your code will keep hold of the lock even when it has yielded the next value - and who knows how long it will be before the client calls MoveNext() or Dispose()? Likewise any try/finally blocks which are used for critical matters such as security shouldn't appear in iterator blocks: the client can deliberately prevent the finally block from executing if they don't need any more values.